# Replace Woocommerce gallery images src using PHP hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to replace single product page gallery images to custom placeholder I have.

I have found this hook:

```
woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html
```

But the [hook](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html/) using the variable `$image`, which his type is unclear (html string/url).

Also found the following hook `wp_get_attachment_image_src` to be responsible of the thumbnails image URL source, but it doesn't work.

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', array( $this, 'pn_change_product_image_link'), 50, 4 );
function pn_change_product_image_link( $image, $attachment_id, $size, $icon ){
    if( ! is_product() ) return $image; // Only on single product pages
    if( $size == 'shop_thumbnail' ) return $image; // Not for gallery thumbnails (optional)

    // Your source image link
    $new_image_id = 1370;
    $src = wp_get_attachment_url( $new_image_id );
    $width  = ''; // <== (optional) define the width
    $height = ''; // <== (optional) define the height
    $image  = array( $src, $width, $height );

    return $image;
}
```

How can I replace Woocommerce gallery images to custom placeholder image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting **width** and **height** to be blank. That's why it doesn't work.

Also, the variable `$image` *(first argument of the hook [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_attachment_image_src/))* is an array structured as follows:

- `$image[0]` Image source URL
- `$image[1]` Image width in pixels
- `$image[2]` Image height in pixels
- `$image[3]` Whether the image is a resized image

Finally, you are using the size `shop_thumbnail` which has been removed from WooCommerce.

> These sizes will be removed in WooCommerce 4.6.0: `shop_catalog`, `shop_single`, `shop_thumbnail`.

Use these:

- `woocommerce_thumbnail` Used in product listings. We assume these work for a 3 column grid layout.
- `woocommerce_single` Used on single product pages for the main image.
- `woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail`  Used below the main image on the single product page to switch the gallery.

You can optimize your function like this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', 'pn_change_product_image_link', 50, 4 );
function pn_change_product_image_link( $image, $attachment_id, $size, $icon ) {

    // only on single product pages
    if ( ! is_product() ) {
        return $image;
    }

    // not for gallery thumbnails (optional)
    if ( $size == 'woocommerce_thumbnail' ) {
        return $image;
    }

    // always shows the site logo
    $logo_image_id = 240; // set here the id image of your logo
    if ( $attachment_id == $logo_image_id ) {
        return $image;
    }

    // set the new attachment id
    $new_image_id = 1370;
    // set the new image url
    $image[0] = wp_get_attachment_url( $new_image_id );

    return $image;
}
```

*The code has been tested and works.*

**USEFUL LINKS**

- [WooCommerce - Image Sizes for Theme Developers](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/image-sizes-theme-developers/)

Comment: It works, just had to remove the array from the `add_filter` hook.
another question though. it changed also my logo to placeholder, how can I avoid that? is there a way to recognize if the image is site logo?